# Send CSRF Token in dropzone

Tags: python, angularjs, django, csrf, dropzone.js

I have tried to send csrf token in my AngularJS/Django app using the following code. The `$rootScope.CSRFToken` contains token value that is received from Cookie object. All other services are working fine with ajax but when I call the service via dropZone, using headers, it gives the error that `Server responded with 403 code.`

This is how I'm configuring dropzone:

```
 $scope.dzOptions = {
        url : $scope.saveUrl,
        paramName : 'newCaseFiles',
        maxFilesize: $rootScope.maxCaseFileSize,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': $rootScope.CSRFToken
        }
    };
```

It worked fine until CSRF mechanism was implemented in the application. Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked by adding `'AUTHORIZATION': $rootScope.AuthHeaders` where `$rootScope.AuthHeaders` contains value from `$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;`

```
$scope.dzOptions = {
            url : $scope.saveUrl,
            paramName : 'newCaseFiles',
            maxFilesize: $rootScope.MaxCaseFileSize,
            addRemoveLinks : true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 20,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': $rootScope.CSRFToken,
                'AUTHORIZATION': $rootScope.AuthHeaders
            }
        };
```